# Limit of absolute value Fourier coefficient

Tags: fourier-series

$f$ continuous in $R$ with period $2\pi$ and

> $f(t) = \sum_{k=- \infty }^{\infty} c_{k} e^{ikt} $

where $c_{k}$ is the complex Fourier coefficient of $f$
then

> $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} |c_{k}|=0$

Is this true or false? If it's true can someone point me in the right direction on how to proof it? If it's false can someone give a counter example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: Thanks ! This lemma is not mentioned in my syllabus thank you for giving me this link.